# How to remove Cache-Control: private for all requests in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How can I remove `Cache-Control: private` for all requests in asp.net

[image]

The underlined Part I dont want in my response header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Cache-Control Header field in custom ASP.NET HttpHandler response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727858/disable-cache-control-header-field-in-custom-asp-net-httphandler-response)

Comment: There is no Duplicate Disable Cache-Header. I tried different ways in Web.config file.

Comment: <remove name="Cache-Control" /> I have tried this also but still its showing the same

Comment: Do you want to remove that header or just disable cache and set value to `no-cache`?

Comment: Did you try `HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Cache-Control");`

Comment: Yes I tried this HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Cache-Control");

Comment: void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("x-frame-options", "sameorigin");
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("no-store, must-revalidate");
        response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0");
    } I putted this code in Global.asax and it woked for me